# How do I change a value of a JSON object with Python?

Tags: python, json, parsing, edit, dump

I'm working on a project where a Raspberry Pi controls some 12v pumps to eventually make cocktails. This is running in Flask, on a local Webserver (the Pi). There are multiple liquor bottles with hoses coupled to the pumps and the pumps are controlled via the GPIO pins on the Pi. This all works pretty well.

I want to add a function that prevents me from making a cocktail if the capacity of liquor that's left in the concerning bottle is insufficient. I've chosen to make a .JSON file as it is lightweight and fits my needs. An object in my .JSON file looks like this:

```
"vodka": {
    "id":"3",
    "milliliters":1000,
    "fullness":500,
    "available": true
}
```

Where 'milliliters' represents the capacity of a full bottle and 'fullness', how much is left in the bottle.

It 'reads' the values and stores them in a Python variable like:

```
x = open(data.json")
drinks = json.load(x)

vodkaBottleCapacity = (drinks['vodka']['milliliters'])
vodkaBottleLeft = (drinks['vodka']['fullness'])
```

I tested if this worked by simply using:

```
print(vodkaBottleCapacity)
print(vodkaBottleLeft)
```

This gives me the following output, confirming that it did exactly what I want it to do:

```
1000
500
```

Now if I let it make me a cocktail that uses 50ml (50) of vodka, I want a Python script to edit the "fullness" value by subtracting the corresponding amount (50 in this case).

I'm getting stuck at this point. I've been trying to use the json.dump function like this:

```
y = {'milliliters':1000} 
x = open(/path/to/data.json")
json.dump(y, x)
x.close()
```

But this gives me the following error in the terminal:

```
fp.write(chunk)
io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable
```

I'm doing this wrong and I might even be on the wrong track so I could appreciate your help!

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: How are you opening the fp variable? Is it in write mode? If not, you may need to set the mode to 'w'. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open Updating json files in chunks may lead to larger issues... If your data is small enough, I suggest re-writing the entire loaded dict to a new file and replacing the old file with it.

Comment: On a side note, I like that you picked Flask for your alcoholic beverage application :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean to update the fullness?

```py
with open(“data.json”) as x:
    drinks = json.load(x)


vodkaBottleLeft = drinks['vodka']['fullness']
drinks['vodka']['fullness'] = vodkaBottleLeft - 50

with open(“data.json”, “w”) as x:
    json.dump(drinks, x)
```